# data_validations in different worksheets python

Tags: python

I'm using `python/openpyxl` and trying to find all the drop down list in a workbook. I'm using `data_validations` that works on one worksheet, but if the data from the list is from a different worksheet it doesn't show.

I read I might be able to use `VBA` to do this, but would there be other libraries that can find this.

Using `print(ws.data_validations)` I get the output below, but I know there are more than 2 in the worksheet:

Parameters:

```
disablePrompts=None, xWindow=None, yWindow=None, count=2, 
dataValidation=[<openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation 
object>
```

Parameters:

```
showErrorMessage=True, operator=None, prompt=None, imeMode=None,         
errorStyle=None, showDropDown=None, showInputMessage=True, type=None, 
allowBlank=False, promptTitle=None, error=None, errorTitle=None, 
sqref='B2:B25 C2:C25 G2', formula1=None, formula2=None, 
<openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation object>
```

Parameters:

```
showErrorMessage=True, operator=None, prompt=None, imeMode=None, 
errorStyle=None, showDropDown=None, showInputMessage=True, 
type='list', allowBlank=False, promptTitle=None, error=None, 
errorTitle=None, sqref='M29 F134', formula1=u'LT', formula2=None]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best way was to use VBA to search for the validation as it will search through the whole workbook. From that VBA will generate a list of worksheet, cell , value. I'm going to import the VBA into python now so it will work.